# How to check a site if it is having a custom 404 page or a default one?

Tags: node.js, seo, http-status-code-404

I am creating a SEO Audit tool using NodeJS. I want to check if a URL has setup a custom 404 page or not. How can I check ?

I have analysed the response for both custom 404 page and default one both return same content-type and response headers. Both return HTML content only so how can I decide if it is a custom 404 page or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is very important for you to know (maybe you are selling custom 404 pages), you'll need to examine the HTML returned by the request.

Many popular servers, such as tomcat, iis, and apache return a standard 404 page that you should be able to recognize.  Same thing with frameworks such as django or rails.  You could build some logic that compares 404 results with the "fingerprints" of a known population of default 404 pages.

For example certain versions of tomcat have a title on their error pages that looks like this:

```
<title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 - Error report</title>
```

If you see something that looks like that you can be pretty sure that you are dealing with the default tomcat error page.

There are  machine learning techniques that can probably do this for you without needing to compile a library of 404 page fingerprints (similar to filters that distinguish spam messages from legit ones).